# How to end a transaction after rendering an HTML return

Tags: php

I'm tring implement this API : https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/native-checkout-v2-api/. I got the response from the server after sending the card number, something like:

```
{
    "chargeToken": "ctok_bcGN8H87tGi1qtxtEoYkliYgMrc",
    "redirectToACSForm": "<html><head></head><body>Hey there! Don't
      forget to render me!</body></html>"
}
```

So I recived a [error](https://developer.vivawallet.com/web-api-integration/error-codes/#rejection-reasons) (Browser closed before authentication finished).

My question is how to render the string: redirectToACSForm, wait for your return and then get the chargeToken variable?

the erro Api response:

```
array(3) {
  ["status"]=>int(400)
  ["message"]=>string(45) "PaymentsCardHolderAuthenticationInvalidStatus"
  ["eventId"]=> string(4) "2061"
}
```